# Polymer app-route return empty data attributes

Tags: polymer-1.0, app-router

I'm learning Polymer and i got some issues with app-route and app-location. I tried a simple example like this:

```
<dom-module id="test-component">
    <template>
        <style scoped>

        </style>
        <app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
        <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/test/:advisor_id/:user_id" 
                   data="{{data}}" tail="{{subroute}}">
        </app-route> 
        route : [[route.path]]<br>
        data.advisor_id : [[data.advisor_id]]<br>
        data.user_id : [[data.user_id]]
    </template>
    <script>
       Polymer({
            is: "test-component",
            properties: {
                route: String,
                data: Object
            },
            ready: function() {
                console.log(this.route);
            }
       });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The main page only loads components and have test-component tags on the body
With the url localhost/test/advisor_id/14152, i see the component but data.advisor_id and data.user_id are empty. I tested route.path and it is empty too.

It seems like i forgot something but don't understand what it is.

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'use-hash-as-path' from your app-location, since it expects a 'http://..../#!/path' syntax for location